# Install Nuget package manager in vs 2010

Tags: c#

I want to get Facebook Login for windows phone 7. I want Nuget package manager for that in Visual studio 2010 express. After installing it I am getting following error This extension is not installable on currently installed products.

Comment: Then how to get facebook sdk to get facebook login for windows phone?

Answer (score 1):

You can't install any addins or extensions in VS Express 2010.

See [here](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/05/21/no-extensions-for-visual-studio-express.aspx) to see why :(

Comment: Then How to Install Facebook sdk for c# windows Phone?

Comment: Get VS2013 of course :)